# Entity Framework persisting entities without identity on primary key

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

Here is the case: We have two databases, one called production and another called test.

I'm inserting the entities in the production database with the following property turned on:

```
Property(c => c.MyPrimaryKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

But I need to replicate this information on the other side with the same primary key, so I just can delete and insert again everything, without worring about the state of related information.

Supose I have two tables:

A  B  C

1  1X X

1Y Y

So I want to update the object "X" without breaking its relationship with the object "1". I could link this objects based on other information, but this is far more complex than just deleting and inserting again with same primary key.

This is the code that do this:

```
        //Turn on identity insert
        var setIdentityOnCommands = new List<string>(new[]
        {
            @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Tab_relatorios ON",
            @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Tab_views ON",
            @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Tab_views_colunas ON",
            @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Tab_views_comandos ON",
        });
            //Get the information from production database
            using (var source = new OuroReportsContext(sourceConnectionString))
            {
                sourceReports =
                    source.Reports
                        .Include("Views.Config.ConfigColumns.ViewColumn")
                        .Include("Views.Config.ConfigGroups.ViewColumn")
                        .Include("Views.ViewColumns")
                        .Where(c => idReports.Contains(c.IdReport))
                        .ToList();

                sourceCommands =
                    source.Views.Include("Command")
                        .Include("Report")
                        .Where(c => idReports.Contains(c.Report.IdReport))
                        .ToList().Select(c => c.Command).ToList();
            }

            //Run the commands above in the target(test database)
            using (var context = new OuroReportsContext(targetConnectionString))
            {
                foreach (var command in setIdentityOnCommands)
                {
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
                }
            }

            //Create a new scope
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
            {
                using (var target = new OuroReportsContext(targetConnectionString))
                {
                    //Execute a procedure that will make the delete job
                    idReports.ForEach(c => target.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_mng_Deletar_Relatorio " + c));

                    //Below is the inserting and checking process 
                    sourceReports.ForEach(c => c.ReportGroup = target.ReportGroups
                        .SingleOrDefault(d =>
                            d.ReportGroupDescription.Equals(groupName)));
                    foreach (var command in sourceCommands)
                    {
                        target.Commands.AddOrUpdate(c => c.CommandName, command);
                    }
                    sourceReports
                        .ForEach(c => c.Views.Command = target.Commands.Single
                                    (d => d.CommandName.Equals(c.Views.SqlCommandName)));

                    sourceReports.ForEach(c => target.Reports.Add(c));
                    sourceReports.ForEach(c => c.Views.Config.ToList().ForEach(d => configNames.Add(d.ConfigName)));

                    //Verify if has any error.
                    var errors = target.GetValidationErrors();
                    if (!errors.Any())
                    {
                        target.SaveChanges();
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is: It does not work =[. The objects keep being inserted with identity primary keys

Comment: Why can't you have your test db be a restored copy of the production db?  Also, why do you care about the value of the PK?  In an ideal world it should be meaningless.

Comment: This would take too much time, we create something within the production database and the replicate to test. In this case we are creating reports. I care about the value of pk, because it will keep the relationship between objects intact, without the need for checking and so on

Comment: Too much time? I have a sql script that backs up live and restores to test. It takes seconds to run. If you want I'll post it.

Comment: Ok, that will be very nice.

Comment: I'm inserting or updating the entities.